# VB CAML Query to select most recently created List Item where name = 'Blah'?

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-online, silverlight

Can someone tell me how the VB CAML Query would go to select the most recently created List item where 'FullName' field = 'Joe Smooth'.

Using Silverlight 5, SharePoint Client Object Model, VB.Net and a list called 'Staff'.

Thanks.

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on? See guidance on "How to Ask" here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either this:

```
<View>
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
<Query>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' />
   </OrderBy>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Name' />
          <Value Type='Text'>Joe Smooth</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

OR

```
<View> 
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit> 
<Query> 
   <OrderBy> 
      <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /> 
   </OrderBy>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Name' />
          <Value Type='Text'>Joe Smooth</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where> 
</Query> 
</View>
```

This should get you the last inserted item in a List